# how to fetch the section with data and avoid empty section in angular2

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a section and data is coming, as i have given static data.
But along with the static data i am getting empty section as well.
So, can anyone help me to fetch only the data and avoid empty setion.

TS:

```
this.Emergencies = [{ 
  "ContactName": "Person1", 
  "Phone": "12345678", 
  "Relationship": "1" 
  "ContactName": "Person2", 
  "Phone": "37438367", 
  "Relationship": "4" 
  }]
this.emergencyContactForm = this._fb.group({
  itemRows: this._fb.array([this.createEmergency()])
});
this.Emergencies.forEach( 
  emergency => { 
  const control = <FormArray>this.emergencyContactForm.get('itemRows')['controls']; 
  control.push(this.createEmergency()); 
  }) 
  console.log(this.emergencyContactForm.get('itemRows')['controls'])
  for (let entry in this.Emergencies) { 
    this.emergencyContactForm.get('itemRows')['controls'][entry].patchValue({ 
    ContactName: this.Emergencies[entry].ContactName, 
    Phone: this.Emergencies[entry].Phone, 
    Relationship: this.Emergencies[entry].Relationship, 
    })
  }  }, 
  }
```

And, i want the empty section to display if data is not there,incase data is there then only data must come

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `control.push(this.createItem());` for all `emergencies`, there is no need to use `[this.createEmergency()]` while creating `control`

**You have:**

```
this.Emergencies.forEach(
emergency => {
  const control = <FormArray>this.emergencyContactForm.get('itemRows')['controls'];
  control.push(this.createItem());
})
```

Change,

```
this.emergencyContactForm = this._fb.group({ 
    itemRows: this._fb.array([this.createEmergency()]) 
});
```

to,

```
this.emergencyContactForm = this._fb.group({ 
    itemRows: this._fb.array() 
});
```

So, now you will not get the extra `formControl`

Update:

```
if(this.Emergencies.length == 0){
  const control = <FormArray>this.emergencyContactForm.get('itemRows')
  ['controls'];
      control.push(this.createItem());
}
```

Comment: is it possible to do that 2nd condition?

Comment: second condition means?

Comment: this And, i want the empty section to display if data is not there,incase data is there then only data must come

Comment: then u can add a condition. to check `emergencies.length`

Comment: how? should i add it in ngOnint only?